# Traveling to Mexico on B1/B2 VISA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, mexico, b1-b2-visas

My parents have B1/B2 visa and do they need Mexico visa if they want to visit Mexico (<10 days) during their stays at US?

When I had H1b visa, I visited Mexico without any Mexico visa. Again the same thing also goes with F1 visa. But I'm not sure about B1/B2 visa.

Any links or references would be really helpful.

Comment: What citizenship do they have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do not need a visa. From the Mexican government's [website](http://www.inm.gob.mx/index.php/page/Paises_Visa/en.html):

> A foreign who has any of the following documents shall not require Mexican visa:
>   ...
>   **b) Valid visa from the United States of America;**