# Travel to Mexico with US B-1 visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, mexico

I like to travel to Mexico from India for a business purpose,

While I have a valid US B-1 visa, I don't have a Mexican visa. Can I fly directly to Mexico, or should I land in US first to get an I-94 card, and then travel to Mexico?

What is maximum length of stay in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's [ask our good friends at Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=MX&selDest=Mexico&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), which is what the airline will do when deciding whether you can board:

> Passport required.
>
> ...
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be  valid on arrival.
>
> ...
>
> Visa required, **except for Passengers with a valid
>   visa** issued by Canada, Japan, **USA**, United Kingdom or a Schengen
>   Member State for a maximum stay of 180 days.  ...
>
> ...
>
> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

Based on this, you should be able to visit for up to 180 days if you have a valid passport, a return ticket, and a valid US B-1 visa. There does not appear to be any requirement to go to the US and get an I-94 first.

You'll wind up with a [Mexican FMM form](http://www.mexperience.com/your-mexican-tourist-permit-fmm/), the cost of which will likely be included in your plane ticket.

Note that if your flight has a layover anywhere between India and Mexico, you'll have to comply with any applicable immigration requirements there as well.

Comment: Do I get multiple entry card??

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fly directly to Mexico.  There's no mention anywhere that US visa holders can only enjoy the visa exemption if they enter from the US, nor that they need an I-94.

(Thanks are due to Zach Lipton, who pointed me to the sources in his comment below).

Comment: There are seemingly legit [sources](http://embamex.sre.gob.mx/india/index.php/en/consular-section/visas) out there (and some of our [previous questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45748/traveling-to-mexico-on-b1-b2-visa?rq=1)) that say that holders of a valid US visa do not need a Mexican visa to enter for tourist, business, or transit purposes. I've never done it and don't know all the details so I didn't post an answer, but it appears the OP has a path that doesn't require a Mexican visa.

Comment: @ZachLipton interesting.  I found none of those sources just now, and it's certainly not mentioned on Wikipedia.

Comment: It surprised me too. Anyway, we've both gone and answered now at the exact same time, so I think we're covered.

Comment: @ZachLipton I would say that an official Mexican government website is a little more than _seemingly_ legit. [The complete visa requirements and exemptions](http://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/) are also on the INM website.

Comment: @MichaelHampton What's a little understatement? One odd thing is that Timatic says that holders of valid visas from Canada, Japan, USA, UK, or any Schengen country don't need a Mexican visa, while the IMM page you linked says that US visa holders don't need Mexican visas, but for the other countries you need "[un] documento que acredite residencia permanente," which is a more stringent requirement. In any case, all sources seem to indicate that the OP is fine with a valid US visa.